# 059 Python: Tensorflow - AttributeError: 'OwnedIterator' object has no attribute 'string_handle'

Tags: python, tensorflow, captcha

the code is as follows :

```
iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(batched_dataset)
handle = iterator.string_handle()
```

i try to run a Captcha crack code which is [this github project](https://github.com/zakizhou/CAPTCHA) and despite the fact that i had to modify so many parts of the code for compatibility issues i face this error and the error says :

```
AttributeError: 'OwnedIterator' object has no attribute 'string_handle'
```

i have been trying for more than 1 day and couldn't and can't find any solution to this issue hope someone help me run the code with No Error!

i am using Pycharm and python and Tensorflow version = 2.4.1

Comment: Without going deeper into how the code, I can see that you use tf 2.X but the soft here is coded for tf 1.X
There is a huge difference between both and some functions vanished or has been replaced by others. It's a big deal to change all the code from one to another...

You'd better downgroad your tf version to 1.X (using env?)

Comment: @Panda50 Thanks a lot bro yeah this was my problem i downgraded my python to 2.7 using Anaconda environment and also i downgraded my Tensorflow to 1.4 and it ran perfectly fine without any tuning!

Comment: No problems. Just few words about python 2.7, it's deprecation until 01/01/2020
( more infos here : https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/ )
Si be carefull with it and a lot of packages won't be able to run on it anymore ;) 
you'd better try to use python 3.6 which is also compatible with TF 1.4